# How can I open an IE window and run a Batch file once the tab is done loading?

Tags: internet-explorer, asp-classic

Here is my current situation. I have a Classic ASP script that gathers data from multiple sources then creates an XML file. Only once the script is done running should the newly created XML file (static name) be copied to a remote server. Since ASP cannot see the mapped network drive, I can't use ASP to copy the file over to our server. The initial Batch file opens the ASP script with iexplore in the command line.

If anyone has better ideas on achieving this, I'd love to hear it. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct ASP cannot make use of a mapped network drive but it can access a UNC file path.

So instead of:-

```
 myXMLDOM.Save "m:\somefolder\myfile.xml"
```

use:-

```
 myXMLDOM.Save "\\someserver\someshare\somefolder\myfile.xml"
```

Of course you need to grant access to this share and folder to the user account under which the asp script runs.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.